# How to delete duplicate cell in a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have SQL Server table with phone number as column name. Now I want to select only unique phone numbers.

The picture shows id ,company name, companyid, phone number.
I want find only duplicate phone numbers not duplicate row.
If duplicate cell value then delete the row.
How can I do that?

Sample table shown here:

[image: Table picture]

Comment: I have a problem here, I am sorry , forgot to mention that, actually I want find duplicate in  a cell (here phone number). i want delete the row if the phone number is exist regardless of company name.

Comment: Use this (use Min or Max. Your choice) Teste the select before : 

Delete TableName
where Id in (
Select Min(Id) from TableName
group by PhoneNumber
having count(*) > 1

Comment: the problem solved Thanks @Elizeu

Comment: Select the answer with useful to help the community. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**ROW_NUMBER()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx)

```
;withe cte1 
as
(
select *,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY PhoneNumber ORDER BY Id) as rn from Table_Name
)
select * from cte1 where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Having clause:
Remenber to teste select before and choose between Min or max id you want continue exist. Maybe you need execute more than once

```
Delete TableName where Id in 
( Select Min(Id) from TableName 
where <create your filter here>
group by PhoneNumber having count(*) > 1 )
```

to help understand Having:
`"Having"` Clause works lile a `"where"` applied to the `"group by"`.

Comment: You can add count(*) on select to see the number of repetitions.